# Hitting Return to save Text Input

Tags: xcode, swift, keyboard, save, textfield

I have a text field on my xcode project, how can I do to save the user input just by hitting return on the keyboard, instead of using a button to save it?

ViewController with the new code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var iphoneSaveCharName: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charOne: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charTwo: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charThree: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charFour: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

//    @IBAction func iphoneSaveTextInput(sender: UIButton) -> Void{
//        
//        let textData = textFieldInput.text
//        textFieldInput.hidden = true
//        iphoneSaveCharName.hidden = true
//    }


    var savedText: String!

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textFieldInput: UITextField) -> Bool {
        savedText = textFieldInput.text
        println(savedText)
        textFieldInput.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }


    @IBAction func editText(sender: AnyObject) {
        if sender is UILongPressGestureRecognizer &&
            sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {

                textFieldInput.hidden = false
                iphoneSaveCharName.hidden = false



                let button = sender.view as UIButton

                if button.tag == 1{
                    charOne.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
                } else if button.tag == 2{
                    charTwo.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
                } else if button.tag == 3{
                    charThree.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
                } else if button.tag == 4{
                    charFour.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The editText function is a long press gesture recognizer that checks what button is being long pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the view controller as a text field delegate and add the appropriate delegate method.

```
class viewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    var savedText: String!

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        savedText = textField.text
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Is is not working for me, check my question for the ViewController code that i just update

Comment: Turns out I did not delegated the text field